# Why does this boolean expression evaluate to False?

Tags: python

Can someone explain to me why the Python interpreter evaluates this expression to be False?

```
1 in [1] == True
```

I would expect that 1 in [1] would evaluate to True, and obviously True == True would be True. However this isn't what happens - the expression is False. Why does this happen?

Comment: Try doing `(1 in [1]) == True`

Comment: (1 in [1]) == True evaluates to True as expected

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`==` and `in` are both comparison operators. And when you have multiple comparison operators like this, Python considers it a chained comparison. For example, `1 < x < 10` is equivalent to `1 < x and x < 10`.

In your case, `1 in [1] == True` is equivalent to `(1 in [1]) and ([1] == True)`, which evaluates to `False`.

Comment: Ohhh now that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have an expression like this python split it to more statements. In fact:

```
1 in [1] == True equals to: (1 in [1]) and ([1] == True)
```

Right side is false since `[1] != True` and whole sentence is false